# Absolute text will be start from the bottom in different places on different sized images

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here the text is in absolute position but if the text is more then the text is coming a little bit above on the image. But I want the text starting point will be the same on all images whether the paragraph will be a less or more paragraph. Can anyone suggest to me is there any other way to do this.
[image]

```css
.case-inner-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  background: red;
}

.case-text p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="case-inner-img">
  <div class="case-img">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/3yLjKqD/inner.png" alt="img"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="case-text">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="case-inner-img">
  <div class="case-img">
    <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=244" /></figure>
  </div>
  <div class="case-text">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: @Xanthous Text start position should be the same in both the images. See the yellow line

Comment: I saw the line but I'm still unsure of what you want exactly, do you have an image/screenshot of the result you want ?

Comment: @Xanthous Text starting position should be the same in both the images.

Comment: If they have the same starting point the long text will get out of the image, is this what you want to achieve ? Also what's the red background for ? Should the text be inside the red or inside the image ?

Comment: @Xanthous No, See the green line the height of the text on the image should be the same.